# How do i initialize a variable in the start of an mfc application

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have a `std::string` object that's been declared in the program's view class.

```
//puzzleView.h
public:
   std::string currentState;    // stores the current state of the blocks
```

i want to initialize it to a particular value right at the beginning of the the execution. But  where do i place the initialization?

Comment: do it in the constructor

Comment: What do you mean by `beginning of the execution`? Does assigning the value in the view's constructor occur too late for your purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what do you assume to be "beginning of the execution". If you declared this string as data member of main view you shall initialize it in view class constructor - in `CPuzzleView::CPuzzleView()` function body (I suppose your view class name is `CPuzzleView`). This is the most usual case:

```
// #1 Using initialization list
CPuzzleView::CPuzzleView(): currentState("No state")
{
}

// #2 Using assignment in ctor body. Also valid, but case #1 is preferable
CPuzzleView::CPuzzleView()
{
   currentState = "No state";
}
```

If you need it to be initialized before `main()` function is started, you shall declare it `static` and initialize in global scope of any `.cpp` file, e.g. `puzzleView.cpp`. But don't think you really need it for such education purpose (?) task.

Also would like to mention that it will be more consistent to use MFC `CString` class instead of `std::string` in MFC/ATL application - to not mix different string types and avoid unneeded conversions.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed explanation, for my purposes i'll be initializing it in the initialization list of the constructor.

Comment: I agree with @Rost for on CString, instead of std::string in MFC applications. I would also recommended using enums for "states", rather than strings, and string comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

you have to initialize the string in the .cpp file.